# Concatenate Related Contact Email field onto one text field on Account

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, process-automation

I am trying to take the "Email" field on Contact records and concatenate it onto the "Related Contact Emails" field (long text field) on the related Account. I would like to have the email addresses separated by a comma.

Ideally, this field would update when a contact is added/newly-related to an account and removed if the contact is no longer related to that Account.

Is anyone aware of how this can be done!?

Answer (score 3):

I preach the gospel of [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) a *lot*, but it's because it's such a good tool for requirements like this and so many admins don't know about it. Free, open source project, fully declarative, can roll up almost anything to almost anything, etc.

Specifically, here, you'd want to have a DLRS "Concatenate Distinct" rollup from Contact to Account, with the delimiter set to `,`. Deploy the parent and child triggers using DLRS's "Manage Trigger" button, set the roll-up to run in real time mode, mark it active, and you're off - without writing a line of code or building the complex Flows that would be involved.

So long as you deploy both the parent and the child trigger, updates, reparenting, deletions, and merges are all handled seamlessly.

Comment: Is DLRS still being supported? last update was 10 months ago.

Comment: I've never heard of it being deprecated or anything. It's a pretty mature tool at this point but I don't know what the road map looks like.