# Formula to check if a text field ends with a variable value

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I am working on a flow to write the value of a field on a child object called Plan to a text field on the parent Account object, using commas to delimit the values from each child record.  So, a given result for the Parent field would look something like this

```
Network 1, Network 2, Network 3
```

Here's the Flow

[image: Flow Diagram]

The flow gets all appropriate child records, loops through them, takes the Network value, and writes the comma-delimited string to the field on the Account.

However, I don't know how to program the flow to ignore a record with the same Network value as what may exist in another record that has already been applied to the Account field.  I managed to put together a deduplication formula which thus far I have been able to configure to ensure the first value and middle values are checked, but I cannot figure out how to check if the end of the string contains a duplicative value.  I thought using the RIGHT function would work, but it does not.  Here's the whole formula currently:

```
    and(
    {AccountTextField}<>{ChildNetworkField},
    not(begins({AccountTextField},"{ChildNetworkField},")),
    not(contains({AccountTextField},", {ChildNetworkField},")),    
    right({AccountTextField}, len(", {ChildNetworkField}")) <> ", {ChildNetworkField}"
    )
```

The first 3 lines work great but the 4th one doesn't, and manages to make the entire thing non-functional.  I'm hoping someone smarter than me knows the right way to configure this?  Thank you!

Comment: N.B. You can do this with no code at all using [DLRS Concatenate Distinct](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246246/concatenate-related-contact-email-field-onto-one-text-field-on-account)

Comment: DLRS is probably the best way to go, but if you don't want to use that for any reason, you could also consider adding customer delimiters to the ChildNetworkField values when adding them to the string (e.g. pipe '|' or any other character you are sure of will never occur in a network name), then just do a 'contains' on the name including the delimiters. And as a last step, strip all delimiters off the string.

Comment: I had no idea DLRS could do this sort of thing!  Thank you!